# Android activity name, how to translate what I have into an Intent call

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to gain information on an Activity nested within the settings menu.

Right now I can log the activity being started which gives me the message

(Logcat output): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings (has extras)} from pid 6270

However this is clearly not what I require to create my own Intent to start this Activity.

Can anyone help me find more information on this Activity?

Many thanks.

Comment: share the code here....

Comment: I don't have any code to share. I'm simply trying to find the Activity name of an Activity within the settings menu. I won't have an issue coding something to start the Activity once I have it's name.

Comment: means do you want to start activity from setting menu?

Answer (score 2):

> However this is clearly not what I require to create my own Intent to start this Activity.

That activity is not exported, and so you cannot start it directly yourself via any `Intent`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Would there be another way of starting the Activity? I'm guessing along the lines of creating an Activity for Settings then going from there?

Comment: @blacktea: "Would there be another way of starting the Activity?" -- perhaps you can lead the user to the preceding activity (whatever it is), then the user can tap on whatever is needed to get into this particular part of Settings.